# SQL Server 2005 Query for getting multiple records which have same pattern in QC project database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

We access the SQL Server 2005 server from the QC Application.

In order to access the data present in the SQL Server 2005 server we use the Dash Board Module in Quality Center Application.

Sorry I could not post images as I am a fresher to stackoverflow.

When I execute the below query I recieved two rows as output.

```
SELECT *
FROM CYCL_FOLD
WHERE CF_ITEM_NAME LIKE  '%Quality Center%'
```

When I parameterised the entity and when I am using LIKE cause it is returning only row.

```
SELECT *
FROM CYCL_FOLD
WHERE CF_ITEM_NAME LIKE   @FOLDER_NAME@
```

Please let me know how to get multiple rows using like clause.

Comment: I wrote the query :). I am getting the output I need.

SELECT LEN(@FOLDER_NAME@),CF_ITEM_NAME FROM CYCL_FOLD WHERE CF_ITEM_NAME LIKE '%'+@FOLDER_NAME@+'%' AND LEN(@FOLDER_NAME@) !=0

Regards, Sandeep

Comment: Are you putting wildcards (`%`) in the value for `@FolderName`?  You should also remove the extra `@` from the end of the statement.

Comment: Thanks HABO for replying to my question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM CYCL_FOLD
     WHERE CF_ITEM_NAME LIKE  '%'+ @FOLDER_NAME +'%'
```